# Iterate through data from AJAX call in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple AJAX call that updates options in a WordPress install.

It looks like this:

```php
function spacepress_update_style() {
    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
        $color_hue        = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'color_primary_hue' );
        $color_saturation = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'color_primary_saturation' );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_color_primary_hue', $color_hue );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_color_primary_saturation', $color_saturation );

        $images_brightness = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_brightness' );
        $images_contrast   = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_contrast' );
        $images_grayscale  = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_grayscale' );
        $images_hue_rotate = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_hue_rotate' );
        $images_invert     = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_invert' );
        $images_saturate   = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_saturate' );
        $images_sepia      = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'images_sepia' );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_brightness', $images_brightness );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_contrast', $images_contrast );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_grayscale', $images_grayscale );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_hue_rotate', $images_hue_rotate );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_invert', $images_invert );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_saturate', $images_saturate );
        update_option( 'sp_settings_images_sepia', $images_sepia );
        die();
    } else {
        die();
    }
}
```

I want to make this function simpler and automatically iterate through all data from the input in a foreach loop, but I don't know how. Hope someone can help me with that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (strpos('color_primary', $key)) {

        update_option('sp_settings_color_primary_saturation', filter_input(INPUT_POST, $value));
    } elseif (strpos('images_', $key)) {

        update_option('sp_settings_images_sepia', filter_input(INPUT_POST, $value));
    }
}
```